# Is there a key combination to get to the terminal?

Tags: boot, script, terminal

Yesterday, I was trying to get a script to run on boot and it worked. I edited the rc.local script so it would do the commands I wanted. However, I rebooted my Raspberry Pi and I can't type in commands. Is there some way of skipping the script and getting to the terminal so I can edit the script?

Comment: You can switch between consoles with Ctrl+Alt+Fx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to the question after digging through posts on here. The key combination is ALT + PRTSCR + K. It stops the script which allows you to boot to the desktop. I hope this post might help other people when searching for the answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please note that you may also accept your answer after a day or so.